# Conditional job execution for Github actions

Tags: github, conditional-statements, github-actions

I would like to conditionally execute a Github Action according to a previous job (`Format`).
If the code needed to be formatted, I would like to execute the following job (`create_commit`), otherwise skip it and do nothing.

Unfortunately at the moment the second job never gets triggered, no matter what is the output of the first job.

My action:

```
name: Format
on: push
jobs:
  format:
    name: Code formatting in Black
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      trigger_commit: ${{ steps.changes_present.outputs.changes_detected }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install package
        run: pip install 'black[d]'
      - name: Run black formatter
        run: black .
      - name: Check diff for changes
        id: changes_present
        run: |
            outputs=$(git diff)
            if ! [ -z "$outputs" ]
            then
              echo '::set-output name=changes_detected::true' 
            fi
  create_commit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest   <- Job never executed
    needs: format
    if: needs.format.outputs.changes_detected == true        
    steps:
      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git config user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config user.email 'github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
          git commit -am "Files updated after formatting"
          git push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the `format` job is named `trigger_commit` instead of `changes_detected`. So try this:

```
 if: needs.format.outputs.trigger_commit == `true`
```

You could use the [actionlint](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint) to check this error, an [online version](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/) is available too. See this [link](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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) .

Comment: Grazie Matteo. Very nice the actionLint tool.